# How to set up tilemap?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble using Unity's Tile map system. I'm trying to make a grid with cells of 90 x 90 length and width, however I can't seem to get the sprite assets to stretch over the full length of the cell. Currently, I'm using 16 x 16 assets, and do not care about the resolution, as the assets are placeholders. Is there a way to stretch the asset fully over the grid cell?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your pixels per unit are correct? Click on your sprite on the assets folder, then make sure your pixels per unit is 16 on the inspector, for example:
[image]